# push an element to new line using CSS

Tags: css

This is my HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>
<p>this is text</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

and this is my CSS

```
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    float:left;
     }
table {
  display:block;
  position :relative;
  white-space: pre-line;
      }
```

I wish to keep my table below the div box while keeping the text in-line with the box. I only want to do this by changing the CSS properties of table or div but not of p.

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

`table { clear: left; }` could do it, added to your existing CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `clear: both` or `clear:left` to your table CSS

```
table {
  clear: both; /*clear: left;*/
  display:block;
  position :relative;
  white-space: pre-line;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

---

```
<div id="box"></div>
<p>this is text</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

---

```
#box
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
table
{
    clear:both;
}
```

**Fiddle**

---

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JH3tN/9/)**

**Output:**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `clear: both` take a look http://jsfiddle.net/qmxp9/